# MySQL COUNT very slow

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pertemba_client_raw_data` (
  `line_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'References pertemba_client_feed_log.feed_id',
  `data_line` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Eg. The CSV line number or JSON object index.',
  `property_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Eg. The CSV header or JSON key.',
  `property_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Eg. The CSV field value or JSON object value.',
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`line_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pertemba_client_raw_data_line_id_pk` (`line_id`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pertemba_client_raw_data_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`feed_id`) REFERENCES `pertemba_client_feed_log` (`feed_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=113121 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Which currently contains about 110,000 records, but will become much larger.

I have a php process running against this table that is running very slowly - the run time is currently 10+ minutes. When I repeatedly run `show PROCESSLIST;` this query in the process is always running:

```
SELECT COUNT(pcr.line_id) AS result FROM pertemba_client_raw_data AS pcr
            WHERE pcr.feed_id = :feedId
            AND pcr.property_title = :title
            AND pcr.property_value = :optionLink
```

I would appreciate any optimisations that can be suggested for beating this problem.

Comment: Add a key on `property_title` and `property_value`. A query like this should run way under 1 second.

Comment: @Zamrony P. Juhara Thanks guys, this has worked wonders for my query time! I would mark Zamrony's answer accepted but I didn't see it until I had already followed juergen's advice.

Comment: (Not an answer, but advice) Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY`, `DROP` the redundant `UNIQUE(line_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to identify the problem. Try

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(pcr.line_id) AS result 
         FROM pertemba_client_raw_data AS pcr
         WHERE pcr.feed_id = :feedId
         AND pcr.property_title = :title
         AND pcr.property_value = :optionLink
```

For your query, as pointed out by juergen, I believe you can improve performance if you add index to `property_title` and `property_value` as composite index such as:

```
KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`, `property_title`, `property_value`)
```

After that, try to execute `EXPLAIN` again to confirm that performance issue is solved or not.